Corners detection fails when textbox is rotated

After rotating the text box in the GTK drawing area, the four corners detection didn't work anymore as the x,y vertices were left to their original values. I used this code to update them but still doesn't work as you can see from the picture. The cursor shape changes when it's not hovering the top left circle handle.
static gboolean button_release_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, TextBox *textbox)
{
    if (event->button == GDK_BUTTON_PRIMARY)
    {
        textbox->button_pressed = FALSE;
        if (textbox->action == IS_ROTATING)
        {
            double dx = -textbox->width / 2;
            double dy = -textbox->height / 2;
            
            double cx = textbox->x - dx;
            double cy = textbox->y - dy;

            double a = atan2(dy,dx);
            double m = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            double angle = a  + (textbox->angle * G_PI / 180.0);
            
            //Update the x,y coords after the rotation
            textbox->x = cx + m * cos(angle);
            textbox->y = cy + m * sin(angle);
            g_print("After the rotation: x,y %2.0f %2.0f\n",textbox->x,textbox->y);
        }
        textbox->action  = NONE;
        if (textbox->corner  != GDK_FLEUR)
            gdk_window_set_cursor(gtk_widget_get_window(widget), NULL);
    }

    return FALSE;
} 

This is the checking code:
    gint x,y;
    
    x = event->x * cos(-textbox->angle) - event->y * sin(-textbox->angle);
    y = event->y * sin(-textbox->angle) + event->y * cos(-textbox->angle);
    //Check if the mouse pointer is hovering the rotate circle
    if  (textbox->draw_rect && x >= textbox->x + (textbox->width/2) && x <= (textbox->x + (textbox->width/2)) + 5 
        && y>= textbox->y+textbox->height && y + 9 <= textbox->y+textbox->height + 22)
    {
        textbox->action = IS_ROTATING;
        textbox->corner  = GDK_EXCHANGE;
        gdk_window_set_cursor(gtk_widget_get_window(widget), gdk_cursor_new_for_display(gdk_display_get_default(),  textbox->corner ));
    }
    //If mouse pointer is inside the visible text frame change the cursor shape accordingly
    else if (!textbox->button_pressed && textbox->draw_rect && x >= textbox->x 
                    && x <= textbox->x + textbox->width && y >= textbox->y && y <= textbox->y + textbox->height)
    {
        if (x >= textbox->x && x <= textbox->x + 5 && y >= textbox->y && y <= textbox->y + 5)
        {
            textbox->action = IS_RESIZING;
            textbox->corner = GDK_TOP_LEFT_CORNER;
        }
        else if (x >= textbox->x + textbox->width - 3 && x <= textbox->x + textbox->width && y >= textbox->y && y <= textbox->y + 5)
        {
            textbox->corner = GDK_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER;
            textbox->action = IS_RESIZING;
        }
        else if (x >= textbox->x && x <= textbox->x + 5 &&  y >= textbox->y + textbox->height - 3 && y <= textbox->y + textbox->height)
        {
            textbox->corner = GDK_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER;
            textbox->action = IS_RESIZING;
        }
        else if (x >= textbox->x + textbox->width - 3 && x <= textbox->x + textbox->width && y >= textbox->y + textbox->height - 5 && y <= textbox->y + textbox->height)
        {
            textbox->corner = GDK_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER;
            textbox->action = IS_RESIZING;
        }
        else
        {
            textbox->corner = GDK_FLEUR;
            textbox->action = IS_DRAGGING;
        }
        gdk_window_set_cursor(gtk_widget_get_window(widget), gdk_cursor_new_for_display(gdk_display_get_default(),  textbox->corner ));
    }

Where am I wrong?

How are you rotating the text box? Your code example only shows some x/y computation, but not how this is applied to anything. Also, I did not know that GTK allows 2D rotations, so... I am curious what you are actually doing.

I'm using cairo. I edited the post showing the rotation code. Thanks for replying.

Okay, now I am confused. I somehow thought you were rotating a GTK textbox, but instead you created your own textbox...? So, what is "the four corner detection"? Is that something you implemented yourself or does it come from GTK? How are you taking the rotation into account for that corner detection "something"?

Yep I implemented it myself. I do the check on x and y values plus the width and height according to the corner which the mouse hovers on. I take the rotation into account by using the new values of x and y I calculate with sin() and cos() in the first code snippet. This code is in the button release event so that when the rotation has ended the new x,y values are replaced into the original x,y coordinates of the textbox. Please let me know if you have any idea why the checks still remains with the old x,y values despite they are changed as I print them in the console.

Could you please post your checking code?

@Krokomot: I added it above, thank you so much for your interest.

Your if works in screen coordinates, doesn't it? It uses the x/y coordinate of it and produces a rectangle around it. I think you'd have to transform event->x and y to the textbox coordinate system and use that for the rectangle. However, I'm too lazy to figure out the math right now...

The correct code to rotate the mouse coordinates is this one:
static void transform_coords(TextBox *textbox, double x, double y, double *tx, double *ty)
{
double cx = textbox->x + textbox->width / 2;
double cy = textbox->y + textbox->height / 2;

// Translate to origin
x -= cx;
y -= cy;

// Rotate
double rx = x * cos(-textbox->angle) - y * sin(-textbox->angle);
double ry = x * sin(-textbox->angle) + y * cos(-textbox->angle);

// Translate back
*tx = rx + cx;
*ty = ry + cy;
}


You rotate the textbox, but you don't really consider this when checking whether the mouse pointer is within the box. Though you use the rotated point coordinates, you don't take into account, that the box's sides have been rotated, too, and now lie diagonally in the 2D space. In other words -- your checking area doesn't correspond to your textbox area anymore. Take the time to draw the rotated textbox and the checks you perform with a pen on paper and you'll see what I mean soon.
An easy approach would be to "revert" the rotation during checking by applying the inverse rotation, i.e. with negated angle, to the mouse pointer's coordinates and to check the result against the values for the unrotated textbox. In other words, you would have to transform the mouse pointer's coordinates from screen coordinates to object (textbox) coordinates, as mentioned by Uli Schlachter in his comment. You would have to preserve the original coordinates of the textbox, though.
A more sophisticated approach would be to use an algorithm for checking whether a point is within a convex polygon. If need be simplify for your case. A starting point could be this Stackoverflow thread. In this case your calculations would completely be performed in screen coordinates.

I agree, I came to the same conclusion in the meantime. Can you please point me to some examples on how to transform the mouse pointer's coordinates from screen coordinates to object (textbox) coordinates?

You rotate your textbox with angle. Assuming you're not performing any translations and scalings, just rotate the coordinate values of the mouse pointer with -angle (negated angle for inverse rotation) and use the calculated values for your "4-corner-check". That's it, no complex magic here.

I rotated the mouse coords like these:
static gboolean motion_notify_event(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventMotion *event, TextBox *textbox)
{
gint x,y;
x = event->x * cos(-textbox->angle) - event->y * sin(-textbox->angle);
y = event->y * sin(-textbox->angle) + event->y * cos(-textbox->angle);

....
But still no detection after the rotation. Is the code correct?

The rotation looks correct. But are you comparing these values against the unrotated textbox coordinates (not overwritten but preserved) ? If you compare against the rotated textbox coords, your check will fail.

Yep it's against the UNrotated textbox. The detection still works as the original horizontal position. Do you have any idea why?

I have a vague feeling. Could you update your sample code in the OP and if possible add debug values? Coords of the textbox (x, y, width, height) and the mouse pointer (x, y), rotated and unrotated.

I updated the code. Not sure about the x,y values. Do you want them here in these comments?

Mate, it came to my mind that when I rotate the textbox, the top left x and y coords change. So to get the detection working when I hover this corner for example, I have to check against the ROTATED textbox. Why do you say the check has to be against the UNrotated one?

The following two situations are equivalent -- (1) Comparing the pointer position to the rotated texbox within screen space, applying an algorithm for point-in-convex-polygon detection. -- (2) Easier, comparing the pointer position, rotated by the negated angle which has been applied onto the textbox, against the unrotated textbox, i.e. in within object (box) space.

I read your code and I have the impression, that you compare the correctly backrotated pointer coords against the overwritten, i.e. rotated, textbox coords, and not against preserved original box coords. Please check exactly value by value, which coords you really compare.

Let it say clear -- you can compare against the rotated box, but you will have to execute the point-in-convex-polygon check, which will require to rewrite your current checking code. You can reuse your current code, if you rotate the pointer coords into the unrotated box representation instead.

Related -- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86420/how-do-i-calculate-the-distance-between-a-point-and-a-rotated-rectangle, but think about distance = 0 and rotation around origin (what you correctly do now). There are similar questions to find elsewhere, e.g. https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110229/how-do-i-efficiently-check-if-a-point-is-inside-a-rotated-rectangle. 1st answer for advanced approaches, 2nd for the rotation approach.
