Calculate new X,Y rectangle coords after rotation

How to correctly calculate X1 after the rectangle was rotated 30 degrees? The X point is 164,83 before the rotation. I used this code:
void rotate_rectangle(double x, double y, double angle, double* new_x, double* new_y) {
  // Convert angle to radians
  double angle_rad = angle * M_PI / 180.0;

  // Calculate coordinates of top-left corner relative to center
  double rel_x = -w / 2;
  double rel_y = -h / 2;

  // Rotate top-left corner around center
  double new_rel_x = rel_x * cos(angle_rad) - rel_y * sin(angle_rad);
  double new_rel_y = rel_x * sin(angle_rad) + rel_y * cos(angle_rad);

  // Calculate new coordinates of top-left corner
  *new_x = x + new_rel_x;
  *new_y = y + new_rel_y;
}

But as you can see from the printed output when the mouse points at X1 the coords are 190,35 but the calculation gives 89 and 11.
Can someone share some light on this? Google didn't help sadly.

Yes you are right, they are related to the top-left corner. I modified the last lines like this:
*new_x = x + w/2 + new_rel_x;
*new_y = y + y/2 + new_rel_y;
But still I don't get the same results. Where is the catch?

Remember to calculate the original coordinate as polar coordinate, relative to (x+w/2) and (y+h/2). I.E. you need to get its angle and radius relative to your rect center. Then the updated position uses that same radius, but an angle that's equal to (original angle + rotation angle).

Calculate the original coordinate as polar coordinate, relative to the center of the rectangle (x+w/2,y+h/2), i.e. get its representation as an angle and magnitude. Then the updated position has the same magnitude, with an angle that's equal to the original angle plus the rotation you added.
Getting the Euclidean coordinate is then a matter of x=cos(a) and y=sin(a), rather than using the full rotation matrix:
void rotate_rectangle(double x, double y, double angle, double* new_x, double* new_y) {
  double dx = -w/2;
  double dy = -h/2;

  // Get the center offset
  double cx = x - dx;
  double cy = y - dy;

  // Get (x,y) as polar coordinate
  double a = atan2(dy, dx);
  double m = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

  // Then all we need to do is update that angle
  angle = a + angle * M_PI / 180.0;

  // And then we convert back to euclidean
  *new_x = cx + m * cos(angle);
  *new_y = cy + m * sin(angle);
}

With an on-page example:


const d = gfx.width;
const ctx = gfx.getContext(`2d`);
const { atan2, cos, sin, sqrt, PI } = Math;
const rad = (v) => (v / 180) * PI;
let angle = 0;

function rotateCoordinate(x, y, w, h, angle) {
  const dx = -w/2;
  const dy = -h/2;

  // Get the center offset
  const cx = x - dx;
  const cy = y - dy;

  // Get (x,y) as polar coordinate
  const a = atan2(dy, dx);
  const m = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

  // Then all we need to do is update that angle
  angle = a + rad(angle);

  // And then we convert back to euclidean
  return {
    x: cx + m * cos(angle),
    y: cy + m * sin(angle),
  };
}

function drawRectAndPoint(x, y, w, h) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawNextFrame() {
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,d,d);

  // first the normal rect
  ctx.strokeStyle = `grey`;
  drawRectAndPoint(10, 50, 130, 50);

  // then rotated about the center
  ctx.translate(d / 2, d / 2);
  ctx.rotate(rad(angle));
  ctx.translate(-d / 2, -d / 2);
  ctx.strokeStyle = `red`;
  drawRectAndPoint(10, 50, 130, 50);
  ctx.resetTransform();

  // And then we draw our "own" rotated point
  const { x, y } = rotateCoordinate(10, 50, 130, 50, angle);
  ctx.strokeStyle = `purple`;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(x - 1, y - 1, 3, 3);
  ctx.stroke();

  angle = (angle + 0.25) % 360;
  requestAnimationFrame(drawNextFrame);
}

drawNextFrame();
<canvas id="gfx" width="150" height="150"></canvas>




Thank you for the code. However I get new x and y with these values: 287 and 195 which are quite far from the mouse x,y coords when it hovers the top left corner of the rotated rectangle: 191,37

Fairly silly mistake, the dx and dy were a copy paste screwup. Fixed that, and added the code running in JS on-page so you can see it working.

You are a GENIUS, mate! Finally it WOOOORKS! You can't imagine how many pages I read on google and how many videos I watched on youtube to get to the solution! NONE of them reported the calculations you wrote! Would you please tell me where to study/which book to buy to learn these concepts?

It's basically graphics related linear algebra. I'm the wrong person to ask for books or the like, but if you search for that specific flavour of linear algebra you should be able to find a decent number of resources. The important parts are understanding affine transforms (i.e. translation, rotation, scale, and shear), as well as homogeneous projection (where you do 2D work in 3D, and 3D work in 4D, so you can do all your affine transforms at once instead of needing to run them as a sequence of operations. Something we're not doing in this code, but could do if we really wanted to)

This textbox is part of a bigger project I started back in 2009. I'm trying to modernize it by adding modern gui parts. Would you like to help? You can find the project here: https://imagination.sourceforge.net/ I replaced spawning the ffmpeg command with libav and I started a timeline project to be hopefully added here: https://github.com/colossus73/gtk_timeline

I'll have to decline.

Ok no worries. Thank you again for your very kind help.

But remember that you posted on Stackoverflow: when asking a question, you're expected to upvote useful answers, and accept the answer that solved your problem. The site wouldn't be very useful without that =)

I just did, sorry about that, I'm not used to post here. May I kindly ask you another small help?

Not from me specifically, no. If you have more problems you need help with, that'll have to be a new post.

It's a new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78784823/2d-rotating-matrix-for-4-vertices/
